# How to redirect to a different action in a different controller?

Tags: c#, .net

So for my own fun I am developing something similar to wordle, I have created the database structure, the start page, and a form for submitting your user name.

Here is my `Index.cshtml`:

```
@model PlayerModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "GUESSING GAME";
}

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-1">Guessing game</h1>

</div>

<div class="text-left">
    <h2>Game rules:</h2>
    <ul>
    <li>Program chooses a random secret number with 4 digits.</li>
    <li>All digits in the secret number are different.</li>
    <li>Player has 8 tries to guess the secret number.</li>
    <li>After each guess program displays the message "M:m; P:p" where:</li>
        <ul>
            <li>m - number of matching digits but not on the right places</li>
            <li>p - number of matching digits on exact places</li>
        </ul>
    <li>Game ends after 8 tries or if the correct number is guessed.</li>
</ul>
<div class="text-center">

<h3>Input your name:</h3>
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <span>Enter Your Name:</span> @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)<br />
 
    <input id = "Submit" type = "submit" value = "submit" />
}

<strong>User Name: </strong> @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.Name)<br />

</div>

</div>
```

As you can see, after this form is submitted I am trying to redirect the user to the `Game.cshtml` view where I the `GameController`, but I can't seem to get this part working, it just throws out this error:

> No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:7197/GameController/Game

Here is my `HomeController` for Index

```
using GuessingGameWRDLE.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace GuessingGameWRDLE.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;

        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            List<PlayerModel> players = new List<PlayerModel>();

            using(var db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                players = db.Players.ToList();
            }

            ViewBag.players = players;

            return View("Index");
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public IActionResult Index(PlayerModel player)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                List<PlayerModel> players = new List<PlayerModel>();

                using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
                {
                    db.Add(player);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                    players = db.Players.ToList();
                }

                ViewBag.players = players;
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Game","GameController");
        }

        [ResponseCache(Duration = 0, Location = ResponseCacheLocation.None, NoStore = true)]
        public IActionResult Error()
        {
            return View(new ErrorViewModel { RequestId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier });
        }
    }
}
```

If somebody  help me find what I am doing wrong and point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated.

UPDATE:
Here is my `GameController`

```
using GuessingGameWRDLE.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace GuessingGameWRDLE.Controllers
{
    public class GameController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Game()
        {
            List<PlayerModel> players = new List<PlayerModel>();
            using (var db = new DatabaseContext())
            {
                players = db.Players.ToList();
            }
            ViewBag.players = players;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have action `Game` in `GameController`?

Comment: @GSerg Yes, please see my update.
And if you are wondering where my views are they are in `Views/Home/Game.cshtml`

Comment: They should be in `Views/Game/Game.cshtml` though.

Comment: @GSerg after creating a new folder and moving the view there I still get the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of this
return RedirectToAction("Game","GameController");

it should be RedirectToAction("Game","Game");

here first parameter of RedirectToAction is action name and second one is
controller name